# What is the best approach to bind to different port on same handler in Netty?

Tags: java, nio

Please review the below code. Here i am trying to listen two ports with same factory. Only one port listening right now. Please suggest how to achieve multiple port listening with same factory for same handler function for all ports.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);
    ChannelPipelineFactory cpf = new ChannelPipelineFactory()
    {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline()
        {
            return Channels.pipeline(new testHandler());
        }
    };
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(cpf);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);  
    ChannelGroup allChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup();
    Channel serverChannel = bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));
    allChannels.add(serverChannel);
    Channel serverChannel1 = bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(6000));
    allChannels.add(serverChannel1);
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));
}
```

Comment: The third bind can't work, as you've already bound to port 5000, and you're throwing away the result, so it's pointless anyway, but the other two should  work. Where's your evidence?

Comment: Thanks for reply
Yes , I removed the duplicate code binding."bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));". But when I run the code it always listen last port[6000]. Is ther any else approach to achieve multiple ports listening either with single factory or multiple factory.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple ServerBootstrap instances. Each ServerBootstrap use a Server Channel to bind.